# Subdomain url redirect to a URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

We have about 50 URLs that need to be redirected, but subdomain names may differ, for example:

```
http://abc.OLDdomain.com > http://cba.NEWdomain.com
http://foo.OLDdomain.com > http://bar.NEWdomainc.com
```

Most of the answers suggest rules, but in our case source / target subdomains often differ, so it's not a straightforward redirect rule that could solve it.

Also, can you do this type of redirect without rewrite rules?

So ideally something like

```
redirect 301 abc.OLDdomain.com http://cba.NEWdomain.com
```

Which does not currently work

I'm asking if there's a way to do it without rewrite rules because the htaccess is managed by someone who's not tech savvy but understands simple redirect directives such as the one above.

---

My current working solution with rewriterule/rewritecond is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.OLDdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cba.NEWdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.OLDdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bar.NEWdomainc.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC,L,QSA]
```

If there's a one liner alternative without "RewriteCond and RewriteRule" that would be great

Comment: We cannot really help here, you need to provide much more information about your specific situation. Do you have some form of mapping from source and target host name (sometimes dubbed "subdomain")? And why are you looking for a solution without redirection rules?

Comment: Hi Arkascha, thank you for your reply. Just updated the question with more details. Thank you

Comment: There is no more compact alternative if you want to implement these redirections on the level of the http server. But you should consider using the real http server configuration files instead of dynamic configuration files (".htaccess") for various reasons (for example performance). The only real alternative is to implement a redirection logic on content level, so for example in a php script that forwards the client, but obviously this also leads to a lower performance.

Comment: got it thank you! feel free to leave that as the answer so i can accept it